# How to get the unique keys of an array of object by underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an `array` of object, and want to get the unique keys by underscore, how can I do that?

```
Array[ Object{a: 1, b: 2}, Object{b: 3, c: 4, d: 5} ]
```

I want to get:

```
Array[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore solution:

```
_.chain(xs).map(_.keys).flatten().unique().value();
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/vagup/1/edit

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
keys = _.keys(_.extend.apply({}, array))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Pure ES6 solution** using [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
Object.keys({...objA, ...objB});
```

**Background**

It takes the properties of the items (`objA`, `objB`) and "unwraps" them, then it combines these properties into a single object (see `{ }`). Then we take the keys of the result.

TypeScript transpile output (ES5):

```
// Helper function
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || Object.assign || function(t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};

// Compile output
// Note that it's NOT lodash or underscore but the helper function from above
Object.keys(__assign({}, objA, objB));
```

Comment: Hey man, you shouldn't downvote a perfectly working solution! Ask for details, I'll do it anyways. Plus flag it to delete? Srsly...

Answer (score 0):

Use _.keys() to get all keys in the object

```
var result = [];
_.each(obj, function(prop){
   var temp = _.keys(prop);
   _.each(temp, function(value){
      result.push(value);
   })
});
console.log(result);
```

_.contains([],value) checks value is exiting in the array or not and return 'true', if it exists; 'false', otherwise.The following is for eliminating duplicated keys and then pushes keys to result array.

```
var result = [];
_.each(obj, function(prop){
    var temp = _.keys(prop);
    _.each(temp, function(value){
       var flag = _.contains(result, value);
       if(!flag){
         result.push(value);
       }
    });
});
console.log(result);
```