# chaining in lodash / underscore ending with pull

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to learn chaining in lodash/underscore..

I found a nice chaining code [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603364/how-to-get-the-unique-keys-of-an-array-of-object-by-underscore)

```
var xs = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 3, c: 4, d: 5}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(
_(xs).map(_.keys).flatten().unique().value()));
```

Now, I would like to remove a value 'b' from the resultant array.

Without chaining I could have done the following..

```
_.pull(list, 'b'); // ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

What would I do if I wanted to continue the chain or is chaining only possible in specific conditions..

Thanks

Comment: You read the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#_) documentation for chaining. It explains that when you need to continue the chain with `.value()` or not. Just read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`without`](https://lodash.com/docs#without) looks like an obvious choice:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  _(xs).map(_.keys).flatten().unique().without('b').value()));
```

Comment: Thanks, without works but pull does not though pull works standalone.. any reason for this??